# Reading a pickle file in a cloud Jupyter instance from a GCP stream (SList)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pickle, jupyter-lab

I am working with some large data in Google Cloud Platform storage, using a Jupyterlab notebook in GCP Vertex AI Workbench in order to avoid local storage and data transfer.

Some of my problems are solved by using `gcloud` pipes to run some useful operations in the style of Linux command lines.  For example:

```
s_path_final = 'gs://bucket_name/filename.txt'
s_pattern = 'search_target_text'
```

```
!gsutil cp {s_path_final} - | egrep -m 1 '{s_pattern}'
```

finds the first occurrence of the search text in the text file as desired.

What **isn't** working is reading a Python pickle file streaming from the GCP bucket.  For example,

```
import io
s_stream_out = !gsutil cp {GS_path_to_pickle} -
df = pd.read_pickle(io.StringIO(s_stream_out.n))
```

errors with message `a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`.

`s_stream_out` seems to be an object of type `SList` (cf. https://gist.github.com/parente/b6ee0efe141822dfa18b6feeda0a45e5) that I don't know what to do with.  Is there a way to reassemble it appropriately?  Simple-minded solutions like running a string join on it didn't help.

I don't really understand pickle, I'm afraid, but I gather it's a sort of serialized format for saving Python objects, so in the best case, a solution to all this would allow some kind of looping through its serial structure and pulling the items one-by-one directly back into Python memory, without trying to save or re-create the whole pickle file locally or in memory.

Comment: If you use `io.BytesIO(s_stream_out.n.encode('ascii'))` does that do the trick? But yeah I’d definitely recommend using a client library for this rather than mixing command line and python like this.

Comment: In fact you should be able to provide the gs:// path directly to pd.read_pickle if your auth is set up correctly

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're going to need to use a Google Client Library directly.

Here's a Python [code sample](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming#stream_a_download) to stream a download to a file|stream that should meet your needs.

I'm unfamiliar with Jupyter|iPython but I suspect that its [String lists](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/shell.html?highlight=slist#string-lists) are only suitable for non-binary data. This is supported by the error message you're receiving too.

I think you could `pickle.load` the `file_obj` that's created in the sample.